# PHP null value returned by function is interpreted as $this

Tags: php

Probably I'm a bit tired and I'm missing something but this, so far, is the strangest issue I have ever had with PHP and I'll try to explain it in the best way I can.

In the class `Compiler\Bids` I have a `compileData` function:

```
namespace Compiler;

class Bids extends CompilerItem
{
    protected $service;

    public function compileData()
    {
        foreach($bids as $bid)
        {
            $buyerGroup = $this->service->serviceProperty->whereEqual('id', 'idgoeshere');
            if($buyerGroup || $buyerGroup === null)
            {
                echo 'BuyerGroup class: '.get_class($buyerGroup).'<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the previous class, in the `compileData` function I'm calling the `whereEqual` function which is set on an abstract class extended by the `BuyerGroup` class.

This is the `whereEqual` function set on the parent abstract class extended by `BuyerGroup`:

```
public function whereEqual($field, $value)
{
    foreach($this->{$this->className()} as $model)
    {
         // I'm skipping some logic here but basically the model
         // matching the conditions is returned...
         return Model;
    }

    // ... otherwise the conditions are not met and null is returned instead.
    return null;
}
```

Here's what's happening: the code runs and the `echo` statement in the `compileData` function is executed producing the following output:

```
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: Compiler\Bids
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: Compiler\Bids
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: Compiler\Bids
```

As you can see, when the conditions are not met in the `whereEqual` function `null` is returned but that is interpreted like `$this` in the `compileData` function.

If I modify the `whereEqual` function to just `return;` when the conditions are not met then the output is the following:

```
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
BuyerGroup class: BuyerGroup
```

Which is correct.

Why is PHP behaving in this way? Am I missing something?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get_class()` function returns the name of the current class (when called from within a class) when called without arguments in that context (which is equivalent to a null argument), thus explaining the behavior you're seeing.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

Comment: Thank you for your time :)

Note to myself: never program when you're tired because you might waste your time, someone else's time and you get downvotes on stackoverflow.

Comment: yw :) I sympathize with your condition and the time you took to post it as a question, I could have been in your shoes there, it's so easy to forget one of those php oddities. Sorry about those nasty downvotes, I will upvote your question tomorrow.